# How to get gobject.idle_add() to pass a parameter by reference?

Tags: python, multithreading, variables, pygtk

I have two threads in my PyGTK app:

- the main thread which runs the GTK loop and does all the GUI stuff
- another thread which handles network requests, etc.

I need to have the second thread get some information from the first thread, so I call:

```
variable = None
gobject.idle_add( function_in_main_thread, variable )
```

In the main thread I have:

```
def function_in_main_thread( variable ):
    variable = 1
```

The problem is that the variable in the second thread never gets set. It's value remains at `None`. So how can I get the main thread to actually *modify* the variable in the other thread?

**Note:** I have some thread synchronization code in the script in case anyone is concerned about modifying variables in other threads. I omitted it from this example because I felt it really didn't apply to the real issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, assignment always creates the name in the current scope. The name you pass is indeed a reference to the variable you've created, but the assignment operator will try to find it in the current scope and, if it's not there, create it.

```
>>> def assign_to(name, value):
...     name = value
...
>>> name = "nothing"
>>> assign_to(name, 5)
>>> name
'nothing'
```

You can instead pass a reference to some kind of instance, a type or maybe even a list, and then use some method of that instance.

```
>>> def append_to_list(my_list, value):
...     my_list.append(value)
... 
>>> my_list = []
>>> append_to_list(my_list, 5)
>>> my_list
[5]
```

The list could of course equally be just an empty object with a "value" member.

In short, if you want to do something akin to call by reference, **avoid the assignment operator**. Use some kind of method of the object instead.

---

There's a neat, and surprisingly terse [guide to Python Namespaces](http://bytebaker.com/2008/07/30/python-namespaces/) by Shrutarshi Basu, in case you want to dig deeper. In order to understand what the assignment operator is doing, check out [wp: Name Binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_binding). It also explains why the assignment operator can't be overloaded in Python.

---

Also, as *you* pointed out, you need to call `gobject.threads_init()`

Comment: Sorry it took me a bit to accept this, but once again - thank you for such an excellent explanation of how variable names work.